# Is it possible to inherit table from another tablespace in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm thinking of launching partitioned tables in a way it is described here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-partitioning.html
I would like to spread child tables over several discs so in case of Postgres it means it should be done in separate tablespaces. Is it possible? I haven't found it in the documentation.

Comment: yes, no problem, there is no relation with the tablespace.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thank you for fast answer! Could you perhaps post it as the answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no problem, there is no relation with the tablespace.